# getAuthEntity fails 'Couldn't match expected type'

Tags: haskell, authentication, yesod, hardcoded

I'm trying to add hardcoded authentication to Yesod. What I've just briefly modified the Yesod scaffold and added a hardcoded user by following the documentation (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-auth-1.6.3/docs/Yesod-Auth-Hardcoded.html). So I have the following code:

```
instance YesodAuth App where
    type AuthId App = Either UserId Text

    -- Where to send a user after successful login
    loginDest :: App -> Route App
    loginDest _ = HomeR
    -- Where to send a user after logout
    logoutDest :: App -> Route App
    logoutDest _ = HomeR
    -- Override the above two destinations when a Referer: header is present
    redirectToReferer :: App -> Bool
    redirectToReferer _ = True

    authPlugins _ = [authHardcoded]

    authenticate Creds{..} =
        return
        (case credsPlugin of
            "hardcoded" ->
                case lookupUser credsIdent of
                    Nothing -> UserError InvalidLogin
                    Just m  -> Authenticated (Right (manUserName m)))


-- | Access function to determine if a user is logged in.
isAuthenticated :: Handler AuthResult
isAuthenticated = do
    muid <- maybeAuthId
    return $ case muid of
        Nothing -> Unauthorized "You must login to access this page"
        Just _ -> Authorized


...        

instance YesodAuthPersist App where
    type AuthEntity App = Either User SiteManager

    getAuthEntity (Left uid) =
      do x <- liftHandler $ runDB (get uid)
         return (fmap Left x)
    getAuthEntity (Right username) = return (fmap Right (lookupUser username))
...
instance PathPiece (Either UserId Text) where
    fromPathPiece = readMaybe . unpack
    toPathPiece = pack . show

lookupUser :: Text -> Maybe SiteManager
lookupUser username = find (\m -> manUserName m == username) siteManagers

instance YesodAuthHardcoded App where
    validatePassword u = return . validPassword u
    doesUserNameExist  = return . isJust . lookupUser

validPassword :: Text -> Text -> Bool
validPassword u p =
    case find (\m -> manUserName m == u && manPassWord m == p) siteManagers of
        Just _ -> True
        _      -> False
```

So it seems that getAuthEntity has been properly implemented. Now however when I try to fetch the user with getAuthEntity like so:

```
getProfileR :: Handler Html
getProfileR = do
    uid <- getAuthEntity   
    defaultLayout $ do
        setTitle . toHtml $ ("hola" :: Text )
        $(widgetFile "profile")
```

It simply fails with the error:

```
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘HandlerFor App a0’
                  with actual type ‘AuthId (HandlerSite m0)
                                    -> m0 (Maybe (AuthEntity (HandlerSite m0)))’
   |
12 |     uid <- getAuthEntity
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I'm completely lost as to what could be wrong. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You're not using `uid` anywhere there...? But clearly `getAuthEntity` requires an argument. Check its type.

Comment: Yes I know, I just haven't implemented that part yet as I got stuck on this error. So it seems you are right that it needs some argument but I have no idea what. In the documentation its:

`getAuthEntity :: (MonadHandler m, HandlerSite m ~ master) => AuthId master -> m (Maybe (AuthEntity master))`

Not sure where I get that AuthId master and there are no examples..

Comment: @AJFarmar So I figured out that I need to first get the authId with `uid <- maybeAuthId`. Now intuitively I thought I should be able then to use `getAuthEntity` by doing `user <- fmap getAuthEntity uid`.

but then I get the error

`Couldn't match type ‘Maybe (AuthId App)’ with ‘HandlerFor App (AuthId (HandlerSite m0))’  Expected type: HandlerFor App (HandlerFor App (AuthId (HandlerSite m0)))` on the line `uid <- maybeAuthId`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I managed to resolve it, as noted by the comment you can't just call `getAuthEntity` but you need the user as well. So I changed the code to the following

```
getProfileR :: Handler Html
getProfileR = do
    uid <- requireAuthId  
    user <- getAuthEntity uid 

    defaultLayout $ do
        -- setTitle . toHtml $ userIdent user <> "'s User page"
        setTitle . toHtml $ ("hola" :: Text )
        $(widgetFile "profile")
```

and then it worked, however using `maybeAuthId` instead of `requireAuthId` will give an error. As to why I am not sure yet.